# Getting the value of model inside a collection of model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a collection `ConversationModel` that have two models in it. I want to get the value of the very first item of the collection. I tried this code `var obj = ConversationCollection.First();` to get the value but it always returns null. Here [image: Autos screenshot] the model's property is populated but outside of it. How can I get those values

```
public class ConversationModel
{
    public SendMessageModel SMM { get; set; }

    public ReceivedMessageModel RMM { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how I create my collection:

```
 ObservableCollection<ConversationModel> cm = new ObservableCollection<ConversationModel>();

        foreach (DataRow convo in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            string _messageID = (string)convo["MessageID"];
            string message = (string)convo["UserMessage"];
            string username = (string)convo["FromUser"];
            DateTime datetime = (DateTime)convo["MessageDateTime"];
            string messageStatus = (string)convo["MessageStatus"];

            string mdt = "";
            if (datetime.Date == DateTime.Now.Date) mdt = datetime.ToString("t");

            if (username == ClientUsername)
            {                   
                SendMessageModel smm = new SendMessageModel
                {
                    MessageIdentifier = _messageID,
                    UserDisplayName = ClientDisplayName,
                    SendMessage = message,
                    MessageTime = mdt,
                    MessageStatus = (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), messageStatus)
                };
                cm.Add(new ConversationModel { SMModel = smm });
            }
            else
            {
                ReceivedMessageModel rmm = new ReceivedMessageModel
                {
                    MessageIdentifier = _messageID,
                    ClientDisplayName = RecipientDisplayName,
                    MessageTime = mdt,
                    ReceivedMessage = message
                };
                cm.Add(new ConversationModel { RMM = rmm });
            }
        }

        ConversationCollection = cm;
```

My WPF Code for the `ItemsControl`

```
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConversationCollection}">
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:ReceivedMessageModel}">
                        <UserControls:RecievedMessageBubble/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:SendMessageModel}">
                        <UserControls:SendMessageBubble />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.Resources>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: It seems that your Models are Null in every entry of the Collection. Can you show where you're adding the Models to the Collection/ where your creating the Collection?

Comment: I added the codes for creating the collection.

Comment: Your question seems very confused - your `ConversationModel` class has `SendMessageModel` and `ReceivedMessageModel` properties and yet your cm collection just contains individual `SendMessageModel` and `ReceivedMessageModel` instances. Do these classes extend `ConversationModel`? Also, you're building cm as a local variable, but what collection are you looking at that is empty?

Comment: @Peregrine Last line `ConversationCollection = cm;`

Comment: Your code is inconsistent. You can't add a SendMessageModel or ReceivedMessageModel instance to `cm` if ConversationModel is what you are showing here, i.e. a class with a SendMessageModel and ReceivedMessageModel property.

Comment: I sorted out the inconsistency of the collection. Now it works how it should be. But there's a new problem. I can't show it in `ItemsControl` where I have two `DataTemplate` that will pick which it will show between the two populated model `ReceivedMessageModel` and `SendMessageModel`. I add the wpf code above.

Comment: @FrancisCanoza You would be much better off ditching your `ConversationModel` class altogether and just have `SendMessageModel` and `ReceivedMessageModel` inherit from a common base class, which you could then you as the type for your collection.

Comment: As you've said I ditch the `ObservableCollection<CoversationModel> ConversationCollection` and changed it to `ObservableCollection<object> ConversationCollection`. Now I'm back to where I started. I can't get the value of the `Model` in the collection of `Object`. Or I did it in the wrong way?

Comment: @FrancisCanoza: Are you trying to display all models in the ItemsControl?

Comment: @FrancisCanoza Make a `BaseMessageModel` class that contains all of the common properties between `SendMessageModel` and `ReceivedMessageModel`. The create the specific message classes that inherit from this base class with the additional properties for that class. You can then create your collection as ObservableCollection<BaseMessageModel> and add both `SendMessageModel` and `ReceivedMessageModel` instances to it. This will also allow you to create data templates for each message type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ConversationCollection` is an `ObservableCollection<ConversationModel>`, it can only contain `ConversationModels` which is why neither of your data templates will be applied.

If you change its type to for example `ObservableCollection<object>`, you could add both `ReceivedMessageModels` and `SendMessageModels` to it.

You will then be able to retrive the first item by casting:

```
var receivedMessageModel = ConversationCollection[0] as ReceivedMessageModel;
if (receivedMessageModel != null)
{
    //the first item is a ReceivedMessageModel
}
else
{
    var sendMessageModel = ConversationCollection[0] as SendMessageModel;
    // the first item is A SendMessageModel
}
```